# Mysql DB Exception while saving data

Tags: mysql

I am using mysql query browser in that i set not null and default value for one column but while saving it is not considering default value it is showing error as column should not be null. how to solve this please help me

Comment: Post your table definition and the `INSERT` query you are trying to run on it.

Answer (score 0):

If you explicitly specify the column in an `INSERT` statement with a value of `NULL`, defaults are not considered.

For example, in the following query, even if there were a default for column `foo`, the engine will ignore it and try to insert a `NULL`:

```
INSERT INTO myTable(foo, bar) VALUES(NULL, 2);
```

---

Either omit the column from your `INSERT` statement entirely (recommended):

```
INSERT INTO myTable(bar) VALUES(2);
```

Or you can use a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger to catch the `NULL` value and replace it with what you want.